# Each TIme i call my listView the content is duplicated

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, duplicates

I have a view where i show all the items from a list.When i enter again that view all the content is duplicated.This is the source code from my middleware were i get the content from the database:

```
if (action is GetPersonalExpAction) {
      dataService.getEntity("experience/list").then((reponse) => decodeBody(reponse)).then((result) {
        List<ItemExperience> experience = [];
        
        for (var element in result) {
          experience.add(ItemExperience(
            id: element['id'],
            job: element['job'],
            company: element['company'],
            date_from: element['date_from'],
            date_to: element['date_to'],
            description: element['description'],
          ));
        }
        store.state.personalAreaState.experience!.addAll(experience);
        next(action);
      });
    }
```

I wonder how can i make that to stop.

Comment: But i want to call it more times cause i can delete items from the list and add and edit.

Comment: I just want to add some method that dont add the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call that method multiple times you have to clear `store.state.personalAreaState.experience` before add database data. Like that:

```
if (action is GetPersonalExpAction) {
      dataService.getEntity("experience/list").then((reponse) => decodeBody(reponse)).then((result) {
        List<ItemExperience> experience = [];
        
        for (var element in result) {
          experience.add(ItemExperience(
            id: element['id'],
            job: element['job'],
            company: element['company'],
            date_from: element['date_from'],
            date_to: element['date_to'],
            description: element['description'],
          ));
        }
        store.state.personalAreaState.experience!.clear(); //<-- clear list before add data
        store.state.personalAreaState.experience!.addAll(experience);
        next(action);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Doing that the list at the first instace sometimes it apears empty

Comment: when it appears empty response database has data? It is the only case in which the list would be empty i think